# Inserting Records via Stored Procedure Not Working (using Tedious MS SQL Driver)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, network-programming

I am working on an app. which has to insert records at an avg. rate of ~900 records/sec.

For this I am trying to build a console app based off TCP which listens for clients connecting to the server using Node.JS as my platform.

I am firing a stored procedure to insert static text (in table) as a parameter to the SP but its not working and no error(s) are caught.

Can anyone pls help me out with this? am new to node.js

My server side app:

```
var net     = require('net');
var fs      = require('fs');
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 7000;
var timeout = 420000; // msec - *420000 

//db conn config
var config = {
  server: '192.168.0.57',
  userName: 'sa',
  password: 'sa',
  options: {
    database: "NodeJSBenchmark",
  }
 };
var lg = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
};

var server = net.createServer();
var connection = new Connection(config);

server.on('listening', function() {
    lg('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
});

server.on('connection', function(sock) {
    sock.setTimeout(timeout, function() {
        try {
            sock.end();
        }
        catch(x) {
            lg('on end' + x);
        }
    });

    function executeStatement() {
    //var storedProcName = '[NodeJSBenchmark].[dbo].[spINSERTsockdata]';
    var storedProcName = 'spINSERTsockdata';
    var request = new Request(storedProcName, function(err, rowCount) {
    if(err){
      lg('Error on insert' + err);
    }
    else {
      lg(rowCount + ' rows2');
      lg('SP fininshed running..');
  }
    connection.close();
  });

  request.addParameter('sockdata', TYPES.VarChar, 'ping'); 

  request.on('doneProc', function(rowCount, more, returnStatus) {
    lg('Rows Changed: ' + rowCount + 'Return Stat: ' + returnStatus);  
  });

  connection.callProcedure(request);
  }

    sock.setNoDelay(true);

    //sock.setEncoding('ascii');

    // Identify incoming client
    sock.name = sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort 

    sock.on('data', function(data) {
        try {
        //lg("CONNECTED: "+sock.name);
        //lg("INCOMING DATA: "+data);
        sock.write(data);

        connection.on('connect', function(err) {
        // If conn is active; hit db..
        executeStatement();
        });

        }
        catch(x) {
            lg(x);
        }
    });

    sock.on('end', function(data) {
        try {
            sock.end();
        }
        catch(x) {
            lg('on end' + x);
        }
    });

    sock.on('error', function(err) {
        lg(err);
    });

    sock.on('close', function(data) {

        try {
            sock.end();
        }
        catch(x) {
            lg(x);
        }

        try {
            sock.destroy();
        }
        catch(x) {
            lg('on close' + x);
        }
    });

    sock.on('timeout', function() {
    });

});

server.on('error', function(err) {
});

server.on('close', function() {
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

SP:

```
USE [NodeJSBenchmark]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[spINSERTsockdata]    Script Date: 9/5/2013 4:16:19 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spINSERTsockdata] @sockdata varchar(10)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblSockData]
           ([inbound])
     VALUES
           (@sockdata)
```

Comment: Please update status, after commenting the `close()` what issue you are facing..?

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni nope din't work and no error is returned :(

Comment: Please try putting in first lines `var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;`. Since with the code given its undefined

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni :d thx for reminding me to add the TYPES.. lol nearly forgot it to add. But still my table is empty – same as before :(

Comment: Can you please show us the SP for better answers to come out from people..?

Comment: Does it prints `SP fininshed running...`?

Comment: No, it does not print anything

Answer (score 2):

Please try adding following code :
`var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;`
 Since with the code given **`TYPES`** undefined

---

Make Sure TCP/IP is enable for SQL
Follow the steps:

- Run SQL Server Configuration Manager.
- Go to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS.
- Make sure TCP/IP is enabled.

Then right-click on TCP/IP and select Properties, verify that under IP2, the IP Address is set to the computer's IP address on the local subnet, Make sure that TCP Dynamic Ports is blank & Make sure that TCP Port is set to 1433. (Tedious by default tries on this port)

---

**Following is the code which is working for me** (TESTED)

```
var net     = require('net');
var fs      = require('fs');
var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;
var Connection = require('tedious').Connection;
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 7000;
var timeout = 420000; // msec - *420000 

//db conn config
var config = {
  server: '127.0.0.1',
  userName: 'sa',
  password: '12345',
  options: {
    database: "NodeJSBenchmark",
    instanceName : "SQLEXPRESS"
  }
 };
var lg = function(message) {
    console.log(message);
};

var server = net.createServer();
var connection = new Connection(config);

connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log('Error connecting:\t' + err); }
    else {
        console.log('CONNECTED TO MS-SQL');
    }
});

connection.on('errorMessage', function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log('Error connecting 2:\t' + JSON.stringify(err)); }
});

connection.on('infoMessage', function (info) {
    if (err) { return console.log('Information:\t' + JSON.stringify(info)); }
});

server.on('listening', function() {
    lg('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
});

server.on('connection', function (sock) {
    sock.setTimeout(timeout, function () {
        try {
            sock.end();
        }
        catch (x) {
            lg('on end' + x);
        }
    });


    function executeStatement() {
        //var storedProcName = '[NodeJSBenchmark].[dbo].[spINSERTsockdata]';
        var storedProcName = 'spINSERTsockdata';
        var request = new Request(storedProcName, function (err, rowCount) {
            if (err) {
                lg('Error on insert' + err);
            }
            else {
                lg(rowCount + ' rows2');
                lg('SP fininshed running..');
            }
            connection.close();
        });

        request.addParameter('sockdata', TYPES.VarChar, 'ping');

        request.on('doneProc', function (rowCount, more, returnStatus) {
            lg('Rows Changed: ' + rowCount + 'Return Stat: ' + returnStatus);
        });

        connection.callProcedure(request);
    }

    sock.setNoDelay(true);

    //sock.setEncoding('ascii');

    // Identify incoming client
    sock.name = sock.remoteAddress + ":" + sock.remotePort

    sock.on('data', function (data) {
        try {
            //lg("CONNECTED: "+sock.name);
            //lg("INCOMING DATA: "+data);
            sock.write(data);
            executeStatement();
        }
        catch (x) {
            lg(x);
        }
    });

    sock.on('end', function (data) {
        try {
            sock.end();
        }
        catch (x) {
            lg('on end' + x);
        }
    });

    sock.on('error', function (err) {
        lg(err);
    });

    sock.on('close', function (data) {

        try {
            sock.end();
        }
        catch (x) {
            lg(x);
        }

        try {
            sock.destroy();
        }
        catch (x) {
            lg('on close' + x);
        }
    });

    sock.on('timeout', function () {
    });

});

server.on('error', function(err) {
});

server.on('close', function() {
});

server.listen(PORT, HOST);
```

Comment: hi, thx for replying. Nope..that din't work :s No error(s) are returned.

Comment: :d thx for reminding me to add the `TYPES..` lol nearly forgot it to add. But still my table is empty

Comment: Hi, sry wasn't able to check this. At Line 39 `if (err)` err is undefined..shouldn't this be `if (info)` ? :D Also, `var TYPES = require('tedious').TYPES;` too. Will check now

Comment: I didn't had any issues with that.. `info` but still update the answer.. I guess I have configured SQL server to make it work.. Just check you SQL stuff as I mentioned earlier.. Hope It helps at-least a little.. :)